# How to change DB location for content

Tags: android, native

I want to change setting in native application (i.e. SMS) by pointing it to different content location.

Ex - At given fraction of time, native application is pointing to list of SMS (`com.android.providers.telephony.databases.mmssms.db`).

I want to point to different location, that might be `com.android.providers.telephony.databases.mmssms1.db`

Answer (score 1):

You can't — the content provider name is hard-coded into the Android SMS app.

Comment: Well, you can make the change if you make your own firmware, but I would presume that the OP is seeking to do this from an SDK application.